# Is there a simple formula for the Stirling numbers of the first kind?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, stirling-numbers

It is well-known that the Stirling  numbers $S(m,n)$ of the second kind are given by
$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{n-j}{n\choose j} j^m$$
Is there such a simple formula also for the Stirling numbers $s(m,n)$ of the first kind?
The one in Abramowitz-Stegun
$$s(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}(-1)^k {m-1+k\choose m-n+k} {2m-n\choose m-n-k} S(m-n-k,k)$$
is a bit cumbersome.Thanks.

Comment: There is a [Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34151/simple-efficient-representation-of-stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind) about this. A simple solution is a contour integral representation, hypergeometric, or, not mentioned in the post, a derivative representation. Which would you like?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Interesting link. The formula $$S_1(n,k)=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y^{-k}}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j {k\choose j}\frac{(-jy)!}{(-jy-n)!}$$
  looks nice; but I don't know what the symbol $(x)!$ means.

Comment: That is the [factorial function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Comment: n! is okay; but (x)! is not defined in that link.

Comment: The parenthesis are just grouping symbols, so when there is a simple argument, they are unneeded; this means $x!=(x)!$. The link also has “$n\times (n-1)!$” implying this.

Comment: Note that x=-jy is not a natural number ...

Comment: It has [this analytic continuation](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Factorial/02/) via Gamma function. The same site has extra information about it.

Comment: So x! seems to be \Gamma(x+1)...